# C# - Is a type but is used like a variable

Tags: c#

Help, i know this post is duplicated but i searched in another posts and dont found an answer, i having problems with C#, can someone help me?
This is my actual code:

```
public void OnClick()
{
    Score = 0;
}
```

i tried using

```
public void OnClick()
{
    Score == 0;
}
```

but it doesnt works can anyone tell me whats wrong please?
Im new doing this so i dont know so much.

- **Sorry for my bad english.**

Comment: `Score = 0;` is trying to assign the value of `0` to a property or field called `Score` -- but if no such property or field exists, you will get a compilation error.  And if there happens to be a type with the same name, e.g. `public class Score { /* ... */ }` you will get the compilation error you are seeing.  But we can't say for sure without a [mcve].

Comment: This error you get when you are using a "type" which could even be a class or struct in your own code as a variable. Is "Score" a class/struct declared in your code?

Comment: could be the OP is simply thinking about properties ??

Comment: Right click on `Score` and click `Go To Definition`. Please show us the source code for the class it went to.

Comment: We don't see enough code. But the error is common and you should not look at google but at your code! Most likely from your post: `Score` is a type, not an integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do something like this

```
// instance field
// i like do use underscore to denote its a private field
private int _score = 0;


public void OnClick()
{
    // assign to field
    // use single equals 
    _score = 234;
}
```

---

[Compiler Error CS0118](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0118)

> 'construct1_name' is a 'construct1' but is used like a 'construct2'
>
> The compiler detected a situation in which a construct was used in
>   some erroneous way or a disallowed operation was tried on a construct.
>   Some common examples include the following:
>
> - A try to instantiate a namespace (instead of a class)
> - A try to call a field (instead of a method)
> - A try to use a type as a variable
> - A try to use an extern alias as a type.

In short, `Score` is probably a namespace or class that has been declared elsewhere

Answer (score 0):

The single equal sign is an assignment
Double equal sign is used in a comparison statement